# Why do we adjust the drift in the geometric brownian motion

Tags: equities, monte-carlo, geometric-brownian

I am building a monte carlo based on the GMB, and I am having a hard time understanding why we subtract 1/2 variance from the drift. If I have a drift of 12% and a volatility of 50%, that would give me "mean" drift of -.24% based on this. That doesn't make sense to me. If I am expecting the asset to drift higher then doesn't my mean drift need to be positive? I am also assuming that drift and expected return are synonomous in this context. Please correct me if drift and expected/required return are not the same, and if so then what exactly is "drift". Not a mathematician, so factor that into your answers and thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are talking about this:

$dS_t = \mu S_t dt + \sigma S_t dW_t$

with the solution to the SDE above given as:

$S_t = S_0 exp((\mu - \sigma^2/2)t + \sigma W_t)$

The drift is the $\mu$ term above and I guess when you say "mean drift" you are referring to $\mu - \sigma^2/2$? The "mean drift" is actually 0.5% from my calculations but that is besides the point.

I originally wanted to write up my own answer but I think [Geometric Brownian motion - Volatility Interpretation (in the drift term)](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/10681/geometric-brownian-motion-volatility-interpretation-in-the-drift-term)
does it much better.

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful! Also you are correct, the example I gave is negative .5%. I had rounded up the inputs in my model. Apologies for the confusion and thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

To (hopefully) provide some additional info to the existing answer:

Following the notation of [Lars Tyge Nielsen](https://financetrainingcourse.com/education/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/Understanding.pdf), stock prices $S_t$ at time t follow a lognormal distribution in the `Black Scholes` world. At time 0, $$log(S_t)  \sim \mathcal{N}(log(S_0) +(\mu -\sigma^2/2)t, \sigma^2t).$$

The continuously compounded rate of return over an interval $[0,t]$ is $$\frac{log(S_t)-log(S_0)}{t}.$$
Given the current stock price $S$, this rate follows the normal distribution $$\mathcal{N}((\mu -\sigma^2/2),\sigma^2/t). $$
In plain English, its logarithm is normally distributed with mean $(\mu -\sigma^2/2)$ and variance $\sigma^2/t$. As $t$ grows, variance decreases towards zero, whereas the mean of the rate of return does not depend on time $t$. However, the mean depends on volatility. The chart below shows this relationship for high vol ($t=1$).

[image]

The reason you get a negative value (for high IV) all pins down to [this answer](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/35519/54838).

> All else equal, increasing vol results in the distribution trying to
> extend itself on both sides of the definition domain but hits a
> boundary at zero, where probability accumulates (probability mass).

Intuitively, this indeed sounds a bit odd. In my opinion, it is best answered by looking at the probability density function (PDF) and cumulative density function (CDF). I ran some code in [Julia](https://julialang.org/) to demo this:

- The higher σ, the more the global maximum of the probability density function (the mode) shifts towards the lower bound of the lognormal distribution.

[image]

- The cumulated distribution function (CDF) shows the increase in the probability of $S_T$ being very small.

[image]

- Last but not least, the effect on the mean return can also be demonstrated by plotting the PDF of the normal distribution.

[image]

The drift in Black Scholes is in the risk-neutral measure $\mathbb Q$. Details can be found in [this answer](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/17957/54838), or [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/8248/54838).